# Python Pyqt5 send arugment to slot using exec and lambda

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, exec, pyqt5, signals-slots

Python 2.7.13
PyQt5

I am dynamically creating/deleting variables which I add to my menubar in Pyqt. 
I am trying to send an argument using lambda

```
exec(a[0] + 'btn' + '.triggered.connect(lambda : self.on_click_fav_list(a[0]))')
```

and I get this error

```
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

why is it not recognizing all this is taking place in the class? Is there something I am missing in my logic?

Comment: Using `exec` like that is a vile code-smell: use `getattr` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So I may have posted too soon. Here is a solution I found using the functools.partial function

```
from functools import partial
exec(a[0] + 'btn' + '.triggered.connect(partial(self.on_click_fav_list, a[0]))')
```

I am still not sure why the lambda was giving that error but this functions as expected